# Invalid property <visibility>, unknown feature 'visibility' in boost build/b2/bjam

Tags: compiler-errors, bjam, boost-build, linker-flags, b2

I want to pass the GCC [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) flag `-fvisibility=hidden` to `b2` using:

`b2 (...) linkflags=-fvisibility=hidden (...)`

but I get this error:

```
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/property.jam:358: in validate1 from module property
error: Invalid property '<visibility>hidden': unknown feature 'visibility'.
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/property.jam:367: in property.validate from module property
/usr/share/boost-build/src/build/property-set.jam:493: in property-set.create-with-validation from module property-set
```

How can I solve this ?

I am using b2 in version `Boost.Build 2018.02-git`

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a parsing problem in the b2 version that you are using: the parsing interprets the equal character `=` from the flag value as the setting of a feature (like `variant=release`).

Use a more recent version of `b2`. For instance the problem is not present in b2 in version `B2 4.6-git` from Boost 1.77.